# How to search a column (multiple rows) for only the first 6 characters of every row?

Tags: excel, vba

There is a sheet containing information in multiple columns. The code below searches a single column and prints the rest of the data in my Userform.

**First question:** the column I want to search (column 1) contains 8 characters, but only the first 6 need to be searched. I tried using `.Characters(1, 6)`.

Sheet1 contains around 5500 rows of data.

**Second question:** I would like to print the data of the row in a few TextBoxes as shown in the code. TextBox2 should contain the result of the searched cell in my first question (column 1), but again only the first 6 characters.

```
Public Sub Search_Owner()

    Dim PrsNr As String
    Dim Found As Range

    PrsNr = TextBox1.value

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    Set Found = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Characters(1, 6).Find(PrsNr, Lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Found Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Nothing found", vbCritical
    Else

        TextBox2 = Cells(Found.Row, 1).value
        TextBox3 = Cells(Found.Row, 5).value
        TextBox4 = Cells(Found.Row, 8).value

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you can by using `"*"` wildcard within your `.Find` method. [More about it](https://trumpexcel.com/excel-wildcard-characters/)
2. Yes, by using `Left()` function. [More about it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/left-function)

This is how:

```
Public Sub Search_Owner()
    Dim PrsNr As String
    Dim Found As Range
    PrsNr = TextBox1.Value
    Set Found = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Find(PrsNr & "*", Lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Found Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Nothing found", vbCritical
    Else
        TextBox2 = Left$(Cells(Found.Row, 1).Value, 6)
        TextBox3 = Left$(Cells(Found.Row, 5).Value, 6)
        TextBox4 = Left$(Cells(Found.Row, 8).Value, 6)
    End If
End Sub
```